# Formatting of polynomial long division with variable coefficients

Tags: polynom

Using the `polynom` package, I have been able to perform polynomial long division as so:

```
\usepackage{polynom}
\[ \polylongdiv{2x^2+3x+4}{x-1} \]
```

However, I wish to perform polynomial long division with variable coefficients. My main trouble with this is formatting it to have the correct alignment. Going line by line from top to bottom in the same fashion as the output of `\polylongdiv{}`:

```
\[\frac{a_{n}}{m_{d}}x+(\frac{b_{n}}{m_{d}}-\frac{c_{d}a_{n}}{m_{d}^2})\]
\[m_{d}x+c_{d}~)\overline{a_{n}x^2+b_{n}x+c_{n}}\]
\[\underline{-(a_{n}x^2+\frac{c_{d}a_{n}}{m_{d}}x)}\]
\[(b_{n}-\frac{c_{d}a_{n}}{m{d}})x+c_{n}\]
\[\underline{-((b_{n}-\frac{c_{d}a_{n}}{m{d}})x+(\frac{c_{d}b_{n}}{m_{d}}-\frac{c_{d}^2a_{n}}{m_{d}^2}))}\]
\[c_{n}-\frac{c_{d}}{m_{d}}(b_{n}-a_{n}\frac{c_{d}}{m_{d}})\]
```

Any help in formatting this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following screenshot shows, side-by-side, the outputs of `\polylong` and of an equivalent `array` environment. The outputs are virtually identical. (Well, the vertical spacing of the `array`-based solution is every so slightly larger on balance, but let's call this "close enough".)

Is the structure of the `array` sufficiently clear for you to plug in the corresponding variable coefficients? E.g., in the first row you'd replace `2` and `5` with `\frac{a_{n}}{m_{d}}` and `\Bigl(\frac{b_n}{m_d}-\frac{c_da_n}{m_d^2}\Bigr)`, respectively. In the second row, you'd replace `x-1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` with `m_d x+c_d`, `a_n`, `b_n`, and `c_n`, respectively. And so on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,polynom}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for '+' and '-' symbols
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r} % automatic display-style math mode 
\begin{document}
\[
\polylongdiv{2x^2+3x+4}{x-1}
\qquad
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{array}[t]{ RCRCRCR }
           &   &      &   & 2x & + & 5 \\
\cline{2-7}
x-1 \bigl) &   & 2x^2 & + & 3x & + & 4 \\
           & - & 2x^2 & + & 2x &   &   \\
\cline{2-5}
           &   &      &   & 5x & + & 4 \\
           &   &      & - & 5x & + & 5 \\
\cline{4-7}
           &   &      &   &    &   & 9
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```